# CAS server default service

Tags: java, authentication, cas

Normally the cas login url contains a parameter `service=XXX`, which determine which service will be redirected after cas server login successfully.

If there is no parameter `service=XXX`, could I set a default  service on cas servier side?

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?
https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/installation/User-Interface-Customization-Views.html#default-service

> In the event that no service is submitted to CAS, you may specify a default service url to which CAS will redirect. Note that this default service, much like all other services, MUST be authorized and registered with CAS.